# Adobe Illustrator RGB mode: hex colors different than in Inkscape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape, hex

Until now, I've used Inkscape for creating simple svg illustrations for the web. I've decided recently to give Adobe Illustrator a try.

One thing that bugs me in **Illustrator** are hexcolors:

1. I create a new document for the web, so the color palette is RGB.
2. I enter the hex color **#c1cedb** for an element.
3. I go and check the color in the web browser, it is **#ccc**
4. The same happens with other hex colors

If I do the same with **Inkscape**, the color in the web browser is **#c1cedb**, as expected.

I'm aware of the fact that Illustrator is extremely powerful and complex, so I'm probably just missing a basic detail here. Could someone help me out?

Comment: Hi seb, could you post an example screenshot? Your question is quite clear, but maybe some side-by-side comparisons could help people find an answer? Anyway, thanks for your question and keep contributing!

Comment: Strange, its almost like its rounding. I've always found colours to be spot on. silly question but you are SAVING in RGB as well as working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, if you follow these steps, this can't go wrong:

- Create new document
- Go to File > Document Color Mode > RGB Color
- Create a square with hex #C1CEDB
- Go File > Export > Save as type : JPEG(*JPG)
- Make sure the **Color Model** is set to **RGB** and not **Grayscale**

> PS: The last step is probably the problem, exporting with
>   Grayscale as Color Model will probably give you something like **#CCC** or
>   **#CDCDCD**

Like so:
[image]

Comment: @seb Glad I could help ;) Keep on learning, AI can do a lot of great things :) Best of luck !